# Concatenating bit vector and hex in VHDL

Tags: concatenation, vhdl

Here's a quick problem for you guys. I am getting the standard "0 definitions for operator &" in this line:

```
if(unsigned(counter) > to_unsigned("000" & x"8000000")) then
```

I know there are far simpler workarounds including just adding a bit to "counter" and using x"08000000" but I'd like to know the right way to deal with this particular situation for concatenation in the future.

Comment: A qualified expression. `if unsigned(counter) > unsigned'("000" & x"8000000") then`. Asking for opinions isn't necessarily useful here. There can be more than one 'right way'.

Comment: to_unsigned is not defined for a any bit string type. As an opinion, why not simply use an integer? eg. 16#8000000# ?

Comment: The reported error comes from the inability to determine the type of result of the concatenation operator. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.2 Literals "The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type". Using a qualified expression would explicitly provide that type (9.3.5 Qualified expressions).

Comment: There's also `if unsigned(counter) > "000" & x"8000000" then` which counts on operator precedence (& is higher) and get's the type of the right hand operand of ">" from it's left hand operand (both operands are of the same type). The idea here is to not use superfluous parentheses. Conditions don't require them for instance.

Comment: Also, since you are using a math type, unsigned, there is no need to make the different objects match in size:   `if unsigned(counter) >  x"8000000" then`

Comment: And you might get the idea opinions are plentiful in the face of 'the right way to deal with this particular situation for concatenation'.

Comment: Thanks for all the information here. I had no idea unsigned didn't require matching for size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As highlighted in the comments, the reason you get the error is because `to_unsigned` expects an argument of type `natural`, whereas you are giving it a vector literal that is of unspecified type.

To me, the real solution here is general coding practice. For the sake of readability and maintainability, you should not have 'magic numbers' in your code, as you do in your example. In two year's time, someone might come along and think "what the hell is the significance of 0x08000000!?". Something like the following would completely avoid the scenario in your question:

```
constant COUNTER_WIDTH : natural := 30;
-- Some comment explaining why the following is a concatenation of two things
constant COUNTER_THRESHOLD : unsigned(COUNTER_WIDTH-1 downto 0) := "000" & x"8000000";
signal counter : unsigned(COUNTER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
```

...

```
if(counter > COUNTER_THRESHOLD) then
```

- Used a constant to set the width that is then used for the constant and signal declarations
- Moved the magic number threshold to a constant that could have a more meaningful name again if the context was given
- Gave the counter type `unsigned` in the first place, to avoid a conversion

Note that I would probably give `counter` a more meaningful name as well, for example in a UART, it might be called `rx_bit_counter`.

---

A huge number of questions on this site have more than one possible solution, so I don't think that makes them all 'opinion based' in the sense that we use that phrase in the question guidelines.

Comment: This is definitely a better way to convey my point. The code is for a DCO where the amount of increment to the counter determines frequency. I'll be sure to avoid obfuscating meaning behind a bunch of literals. Thanks!

Comment: And you could go one step further by using a defining a new type, e.g. `type TCounter: unsigned(COUNTER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);` then declare `constant COUNTER_THRESHOLD : TCounter := "000" & x"8000000";` and `signal counter : TCounter;` This creates a hierarchy of only one version of the truth.